# Ignore JSON deserialization if enum map key is null or unknown

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize JSON into a Java POJO using Jackson. 
The Json looks like

```
"foo": {
    "one": {
        "a":1,
        "b":"string"
    }
    "three":{
        "a":2
        "b":"another"
    }
    ...
}
```

And the class I want to deserialize into has this field:

```
public class Myclass {

    private Map<MyEnum, MyPojo> foo;

    //setter and getter

    public static MyPojo {
        private int a;
        private String b;
    }
}
```

And my enum type looks like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    one("data1"),two("data2")

    @JsonValue
    String data;

    EnumAttrib(String data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    private static Map<String, MyEnum> ENUM_MAP = new HashMap();
    static {
        for (MyEnum a: MyEnum.values()) {
            ENUM_MAP.put(a.data, a);
        }
    }
    @JsonCreator
    public static MyEnum fromData(String string) {
        return ENUM_MAP.get(string);
    }
}
```

This solution works well as long us the JSON has known keys which are captured by MyEnum. How can I skip certain JSON elements from serialization (in this example "`three`"), if it's not defined in `MyEnum`

Comment: may be something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446619/how-to-ignore-enum-fields-in-jackson-json-to-object-mapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` which is disabled by default on your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);
```

When you do this, the result `Map` will contain one entry with key equals to `null` and value set to `JSON` object related with one of unknown fields. If it is not acceptable you need to write custom deserialiser or remove `null` key after deserialisation process.

To solve problem with `null` key in `Map` you can also use `EnumMap` in your `POJO`:

```
private EnumMap<MyEnum, MyPojo> foo;
```

where `null` keys are not permitted and will be skipped.

See also:

- [Jackson deserializing into Map with an Enum Key, POJO Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406568/jackson-deserializing-into-map-with-an-enum-key-pojo-value)

Answer (score 3):

To solve your requirement, in case you are using `Spring Boot`, add this to your application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL=true
```